# Replace + sign from the URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, replace, character

I want to change the URL of my website using .htaccess file :

http://godofindia.com/Guru+Saint+Mahatma-103/

to

http://godofindia.com/Guru-Saint-Mahatma-103/

I only want the + sign to be replaced by - sign

please help

Comment: the `+` sign is a URL encoding scheme representing a space character. The `+` is treated as a space by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that this is possible using plain .htaccess. If you really need to change your URLs, I would use a small script (i.e. PHP) that handles the replacment:

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$new_uri = str_replace('+', '-', $uri);

header('Location: ' . $new_uri);
```

And then, rewrite Requests to that script using a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*+.*$ rewrite-plus.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found same issue, so i am using "%20" instead of "+" sign.

You can check it out that will work in most of all cases. In many site also if you write "test+play" or "test%20play" both work same

May this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\%2[Cc]$ /$1-$2